# How do you build UWP library with different assemblies (x86 and ARM)?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll, uwp

I have a library that is shared between IoT (ARM) and PC (x86).

How do you build multiple projects with different architectures using the same library.

'Any CPU' seems to internally select only ONE of the assemblies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a library between multiple different platforms then you want to use a **Shared Project** (*not a library project*).

I wanted to build multiple projects at the same time with different architectures and my library project was getting internally assigned to just one assembly.

The reason is that a library gets built to AN assembly.  A shared project is at the source code level and gets added into every project that is referencing it.